ESLint: @stylistic/type-annotation-spacing and @stylistic/key-spacing conflict
This is my current eslint config. I am currently using the latest version of ESLint. I would like to be able to use these two rules in combination but they conflict. I also tried to write a custom rule but this also did not work.
// eslint.config.js
import parserTs from '@typescript-eslint/parser'
import stylistic from '@stylistic/eslint-plugin'

export default [
  {
    files: ["**/*.ts"],
    plugins: {
      '@stylistic': stylistic
    },
    languageOptions: {
      parser: parserTs
    },
    rules: {
      '@stylistic/type-annotation-spacing': ['error', {
        "before": true,
        "after": true
      }],
      '@stylistic/key-spacing': ['error', {
        "beforeColon": false,
        "afterColon": true,
        "mode": "strict"
      }]
    }
  }
];

How can I use key-spacing only for keys/values and not for types?
As an example, this is how I want my code to be formatted:
const foo : string = 'Hello World!'
//         ^ 1 Spaces
//       ^ 1 Spaces

const bar = {
  key: 'value'
//    ^ 1 Space
//   ^ No space
}

